# Socket handling becomes synchronous after several concurrent requests

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcplistener

We have a TCP server that accepts multiple requests and handles each with a separate thread. Recently we have had reports of diminished performance and it appears the cause is that requests are being handled serially.

Specifically, the thread that instantiates TcpListener and calls TcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket() is the same thread that executes the callback method.

```
private void ListenForConnections()
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, args.port);
    listener.Start();

    log.DebugFormat("Listener started on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    while (true)
    {
        _accepted.Reset();

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = listener.BeginAcceptSocket(
            new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnection), listener);

        _accepted.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpListener listen = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
    if (listen == null) throw new Exception("no listener?");

    log.DebugFormat("Accepted connection on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    using (Socket socket = listen.EndAcceptSocket(ar))
    {
        _accepted.Set();

        DoWork(socket);
    }
}
```

If multiple instances of a client program are executed simultaneously and each performs a single request to the server in a loop, thus creating multiple concurrent connections, the log might look like this:

```
16:49:08.954 [1] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.ListenForConnections Listener started on thread 1
16:49:18.639 [4] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 4
16:49:18.648 [6] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 6
16:49:18.650 [1] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 1
16:49:21.671 [1] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 1
16:49:24.673 [1] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 1
16:49:27.676 [1] DEBUG SocketAsyncServer.Program.AcceptConnection Accepted connection on thread 1
```

Note that the DoWork() method sleeps for 3 seconds, explaining the 3 second cadence in the log timestamp once only the starting thread executes the callback method.

I have seen many examples using the same pattern for handling incoming request via threads, but no description of a situation like the one we are seeing.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: How many concurrent sockets are you working with here? If it is a handful, you'll probably be OK (although it isn't pretty); if it is hundreds, or a high-volume TCP server (thousands, tens of thousands, etc), then : this is a terrible terrible design - it is thread per socket, which will not work at all. As soon as you saturate the thread-pool, you're dead. Plus it sucks long before then too (each socket has an entire thread plus stack, which is *huge*). So again: how many sockets are you dealing with here?

Comment: @marc-gravell: In the worst case we see 10 concurrent connections.  The example above was created using 5 processes / connections. Thanks for responding.

Comment: (heh, I  commented on the wrong question there for a moment; deleted)